# Irregular disconnections

Tags: networking, internet, connection

I have had a disconnection problem for months, which has been bothering me alot.

The problem mainly occurs (or at least it's when I can actually see it happen) while playing video games.

What happens is:

- My character freezes (think of any online game) and I can't do anything.
- People do not hear me talk on VoIPs (teamspeak, discord, you name it) but I can hear them fine.
- It (communication between me and the game) usually comes back up between 5 and 15 seconds, most of time, I don't even get timed out of games/voips.

While this happens, I am pinging 8.8.8.8 just fine. The whole time, without   a single packet loss.
It happens at random times. Sometimes not in 6 hour, sometimes 4 times in a hour.

What else you should know:

- I am connected with ethernet.
- I have changed my ethernet cable to a brand new one.
- I have contacted my ISP and they told me that it didn't look like it had anything to do with them or the router itself. Saying the fact i'm pinging fine proves it.
- My motherboard (im guessing it could be one of the many reasons): MSI Z270 GAMING M3 (MS-7A62)
- I'm running on win7

I could be forgetting crucial informations that could help you help me, and if that's the case i'm sorry and will update as needed.

Hoping this is the right place to ask.

Thanks alot to anyone willing to help me find the cause

Comment: Consider looking into using Performance Monitory and capturing stats such as CPU, Dick IO, network throughput, etc. and then when there is a problem, take note of the time and go back and look and see what spikes up, etc. The key would be selecting the specific things with the perfmon tool or whatever for helping troubleshoot. I'm not certain how much overhead the capture puts on your system so do some testing once you have it setup and confirm it doesn't cause you problems.